# Serving MP3 with nginx and php

Tags: php, nginx, mp3

I'm trying to serve MP3 files with php on a server which nginx is on.

The problem is when I serve files using php mp3 starts to play after 1 or 2 MB of files got downloaded but if I playback the same mp3 without php it will start to play right away.

I tried adding the `X-Accel-Redirect` header in nginx, but that didn't help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Php doesn't change how you play it unless you try to do it over bash. It's your html/javascript that plays it. Without any html or javascript, your browser picks it up and plays it. The problem with nginx doesn't belong to SO, use [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/)